# Are the VS2010 Web Forms Application Templates available in VS2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

In ASP.NET, I'm targeting version 4.0 of the .NET Framework using Visual Studio 2012.  However, I don't care for the default Visual Studio 2012 ASP.NET Web Forms Application template -- I prefer the template included in Visual Studio 2010.  However, I don't have access to Visual Studio 2010 anymore.  Is it possible to retrieve and import the Visual Studio 2010 template into Visual Studio 2012 somehow?

Comment: Ironically, I know there's a VS2010 extension that includes the VS2012 version of the templates...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding an old project using Visual Studio 2010 and skinned it, and then used the skeleton as a template in Visual Studio 2012.